# Caching AJAX response is not working

Tags: jquery, caching

Hi I have the following code below with a caching mechanism for AJAX results:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
var _doing_ajaxx = false;
$('.toolbar').remove();
$('#mydiv #frontend').click(function() {    
if (_doing_ajaxx) {
    return false;
}

var title_shortcode = $(this).text();


var insert_namex=  $(this).attr('class');


var titlejsselector=title_shortcode.replace(/ /g,'');


var buttonval=$('#'+titlejsselector+' input').val();

if (buttonval=='Minimize')  {
//stop ajax request if button is set

    $('#'+titlejsselector+' div').remove();
    $('#'+titlejsselector+' input').remove();

} else {
//initialize ajax variables
var cacheObj = {};
var data = {
        action: 'test_ajax_response',
        test_ajax_response_nonce: the_ajax_script.test_ajax_response_nonce, 
        postID_from_ajax : the_ajax_script.postid_to_ajax,
        insert_name_ajax: insert_namex,
        title_ajax: title_shortcode
    }; 
if (cacheObj.postID_from_ajax){

display(cacheObj.postID);

}else{

  // Do your ajax call
$.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

    _doing_ajaxx = false;
    cacheObj.postID_from_ajax = response;
    display(response);

});

 }

 function display(response){

  $('#mydiv #frontend').next().slideToggle();   
  $('#mydiv #'+titlejsselector).append(response+"<input type='hidden' id='minimizebutton' value='Minimize'>");
  SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();

  $('.toolbar').remove();

  }   

}); 


});
```

However, I Checked with Firebug and it is still posting request to the server instead of using the cached results.

The above code works like this. User will first click the link and then show the results(from the AJAX response) to the server. The user can minimize the results by clicking again the link. This is the second click. The minimize button will remove the results. If the user clicks again the link to see again the result, I do not like to request again to the server but using the cached results from the first click.

What is needed to be changed in the above code? Thanks for any tips.

UPDATE:  I also noticed the cache variable cacheObj.postID_from_ajax is destroyed (or becoming empty) on the second click when the user minimizes the result. So in the third click, this cache variable cannot be used anymore because its null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an empty `cacheObj` inside the click handler each time. Then after you create it you are looking for a property of it that doesn't exist because you just declared it as empty object

```
var cacheObj = {};

if (cacheObj.postID_from_ajax)/* object has no properties...will always be false*/
```

You need to declare `var cacheObj = {};` outside of the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

The `cacheObj` is local to the click handler, here the same `cacheObj` is available across all click handlers since it is in the same shared context (closure).

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // initialize ajax variables
    var _doing_ajaxx = false;
    //cache object is created in the covering closure since it must be available across all click handlers
    var cacheObj = {};

    $('.toolbar').remove();
    $('#mydiv #frontend').click(function() {
        if (_doing_ajaxx) {
            return false;
        }

        var title_shortcode = $(this).text();

        var insert_namex = $(this).attr('class');

        var titlejsselector = title_shortcode.replace(/ /g, '');

        var buttonval = $('#' + titlejsselector + ' input').val();

        if (buttonval == 'Minimize') {
            // stop ajax request if button is set

            $('#' + titlejsselector + ' div').remove();
            $('#' + titlejsselector + ' input').remove();

        } else {
            var data = {
                action : 'test_ajax_response',
                test_ajax_response_nonce : the_ajax_script.test_ajax_response_nonce,
                postID_from_ajax : the_ajax_script.postid_to_ajax,
                insert_name_ajax : insert_namex,
                title_ajax : title_shortcode
            };
            if (cacheObj.postID_from_ajax) {

                display(cacheObj.postID);

            } else {

                // Do your ajax call
                $.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

                            _doing_ajaxx = false;
                            cacheObj.postID_from_ajax = response;
                            display(response);

                        });

            }

            function display(response) {

                $('#mydiv #frontend').next().slideToggle();
                $('#mydiv #' + titlejsselector)
                        .append(response
                                + "<input type='hidden' id='minimizebutton' value='Minimize'>");
                SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();

                $('.toolbar').remove();

            }
        }
    });

});
```